# Unable to add to Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to run the following code but everytime I run it, I am getting that the `markerObj` array is empty.

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var ExifImage = require('exif').ExifImage;
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

function decimalDegrees(gps, fileName) {
  latitude = gps['GPSLatitude'];
  longitude = gps['GPSLongitude'];
  imageLink = "http://localhost:3000/tmp/" + fileName;
  latitude = latitude[0] + latitude[1] / 60 + latitude[2] / 3600;
  longitude = longitude[0] + longitude[1] / 60 + longitude[2] / 3600;
  console.log(latitude);
  console.log(longitude);
  var markerObject = {
    latitude: latitude,
    longitude: longitude,
    imageLink: imageLink
  };
  return markerObject;
}

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  res.sendFile('map.html', {
    root: 'C:\\Users\\Pranav\\WebstormProjects\\majorProject\\views\\'
  });

});

router.get('/map', function(req, res, next) {
  var markerObj = [];
  fs.readdir("C:\\Users\\Pranav\\WebstormProjects\\majorProject\\tmp", function(err, files) {
    if (err) {
      console.error("Could not list the directory.", err);
      process.exit(1);
    }
    files.forEach(function(file, index) {
      new ExifImage({
        image: path.join("C:\\Users\\Pranav\\WebstormProjects\\majorProject\\tmp", file)
      }, function(error, exifData) {
        if (error)
          console.log('Error: ' + error.message);
        pothole = decimalDegrees(exifData["gps"], file);
        markerObj.push(pothole); // Do something with your data!
      });
    });
    console.log(markerObj);
    res.render('map', {
      markers: markerObj
    });
  });
});
```

Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: Could it be that new ExifImage(...) executes the callback asynchronously? it that case, console.log(markerObj) will execute before any of the new ExifImage callbacks executed, you should await these callbacks before printing the array.

Comment: @Arik - I have modified my code a bit. It is still not working. Any idea what is happening?
http://pasted.co/9c1e6cce

Comment: @PranavJituri the `callback` in the `fs.readdir` function is Asynchronous. so I would suggest to use a promise.